# Joining two halves of rectangle

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've followed [this](http://vectorboom.com/load/techniques/corners/16-1-0-234) tutorial to get 2 corner rounded rectangle.
However, when I try to union those two halves of rectangles back,

[image]

then on upper right corner I got the following

[image]

Merged lines are going exactly to the center of rectangle. The bottom left  corner looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to get 90 degree corners, just like before cutting rectangle with scissors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use Merge. Pathfinder operations such as Merge are meant more for shapes, not paths. Pathfinder isn't really aware of strokes and doesn't attempt to combine or alter strokes as well as it should. Essentially, only use Pathfinder when you want to alter full shapes, not merely strokes.

Simply select the two end points and choose `Object > Path > Average` set it to "both" and click okay. Then choose `Object > Path > Join`. You will have one corner point. You may need to move it back into the proper position after this.

To average and Join in one step, you can use a shortcut. Select both the end anchor points and hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Win). This will average and join the two points in one step. There is no menu item to do this, only the shortcut will do both at once.

There is also a [free script](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1045709) for Illustrator to round any corner which makes the entire processes of what you are trying to do much, much easier. And there's the [VectorScribe](http://www.astutegraphics.com/products/vectorscribe/) plug in for Illustrator which contains a feature to allow dynamic corner rounding (this is what I use).

Comment: worked like a charm! VectorScribe looks very useful for my daily routines and I may purchase it after trying. I love this site and hope it will soon be out of beta :)

Comment: Make sure you mark Scott's answer if that indeed helped. One way to help get us out of Beta is for questions to get answered. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design